# Example of how to properly define a class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have defined a function as such:

```
def quicksort(points):
    if len(points) < 2: return points
    smaller,equal,larger = [], [], []
    pivot_angle = find_polar_angle(random.randint(0, len(points) - 1))
    for pt in points:
        pt_angle = find_polar_angle(pt)
        if pt_angle < pivot_angle:
            smaller.append(pt)
        elif pt_angle == pivot_angle: 
            equal.append(pt)
        else:
            larger.append(pt)
    return quicksort(smaller) + sorted(equal, key = find_dist) + quicksort(larger)
```

Now, I want to change my code - which btw is an implementation of the Graham Scan Algorithm - into an object oriented code. So I went ahead and declared a class in a file MyClasses.py:

```
from MyFunctions import find_anchor, find_polar_angle, find_dist, find_det, quicksort, graham_scan

class Cluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.hull = []
        self.anchor = None

        self.find_anchor = find_anchor
        self.find_polar_angle = find_polar_angle
        self.find_dist = find_dist
        self.find_det = find_det
        self.quicksort = quicksort
        self.graham_scan = graham_scan
```

But of course I have to change my functions as well. I don't want to list all the functions here, that's why I stay with the `quicksort` function as an example. This is where I struggle a lot, since I don't know the python syntax well enough to be sure about what I am doing here. This is my revised form of `quicksort`:

```
def quicksort(self, points):
    if len(points) < 2: return points
    smaller,equal,larger = [], [], []
    pivot_angle = self.find_polar_angle(self, random.randint(0, len(self.members) - 1))
    for pt in points:
        pt_angle = self.find_polar_angle(self, pt)
        if pt_angle < pivot_angle:
            smaller.append(pt)
        elif pt_angle == pivot_angle: 
            equal.append(pt)
        else:
            larger.append(pt)
    return self.quicksort(self, smaller) + sorted(self, equal, key = self.find_dist) + self.quicksort(self, larger)
```

Here's the thing: This function is recursive! So I need it to take `smaller, equal and larger` as arguments. Later, another function `graham_scan` is going to call this function as such:

```
self.members = self.quicksort(self, self.members)
```

I know there are probably many mistakes in here. That's why I'm asking: Is this last expression a valid expression? I mean I am changing a class-variable (`self.members`) but I do so not by directly changing it, but by assigning it the return value of `quicksort`. 
Anyways, help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "function of a class"?

Comment: So I wrote this function without having a class in mind. `points` would be the `members` list of my class. With "function of a class" I mean a method of my class. I want these functions / methods to deal with variables from my class only

Comment: There exists no `self` because at class creation, instances cannot have been created yet. As for now it seems your function is not written to take instances of `Cluster` as first argument, so you will need to define a new method, something like `def quicksort(self): ...` in your class body.

Answer (score 0):

To make an existing function as a new property of a new class, try this:

```py
def quicksort():
    pass # your custom logic

class Cluster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.quicksort = quicksort
        # more properties
```

Python has quite a different syntax to C++ or Java.

To say about the second question, all the variables used in `quicksort` function body are only available in that function only.

Comment: This *will not* bind the instance to the method. `quicksort` should be an attribute of the class for binding to work.

Answer (score -1):

About second question. All members of classes are **PUBLIC** in python. By convention you can add "_" and "__" in front of the names for protected and private respectfully. BUT this does NOT prevent you from accessing them, it just means that you (or whoever reading the code) should not misuse them.
Although, __variable must be accessed with following syntax outside of class:

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x

    def get_surface(self):
        return self.__x **2


>>> square1 = Square(5)
>>> print(square1.get_surface())
>>> 25
>>> square1._Square__x = 10
>>> print(square1.get_surface())
>>> 100


>>> square1.__x
>>> **AttributeError: 'Square' object has no attribute '__x'**
```

Or it will raise AttributeError. Hope this helps

Comment: _By convention you can add "_" and "__" in front of the names for protected and private respectfully. BUT this does NOT prevent you from accessing them, it just means that you (or whoever reading the code) should not misuse them._ `_` is for "private", `__` is to prevent the method from being overridden or used accidentally.